# Ado Api call fails for a specific API

Tags: .net, api, azure-devops, sdk

I am trying to call this ADO API -
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/graph/users/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0

I am azure SDK and have created a GraphHttpClient to make this call.

But this api always returns an exception -
"Page not found".
I am creating httpclients using this org url - https://{organization}.visualstudio.com/

I have also use BuildHttpClient and GitHttpClient for different purposes in the same file and they are working as expected. It's only this GraphHttpClient's API(Given in link above) throwing this exception.
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The **GraphHttpClient** has been **deprecated** and should no longer be used.

It has been replaced with [MSGraphClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/use-msgraph).

For more information you can refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/overview-graphhttpclient?msclkid=73d7f2b4cf5411ec862daae7c8bdeb9a).